# Execute callback after REST API request completes + Response is sent

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, rest-api

In WordPress, is there an action hook or anything which allows you to run a callback after the response to a custom REST API endpoint, registered via `register_rest_route()`, has been sent to the client? Ideally with the data of the request payload?

The closest thing we could find so far is the `rest_post_dispatch` hook, which however still happens before the response is sent to the client.

Context: The reason why we have to do this is to execute multiple API calls after a successful REST API call, whose completion is irrelevant for the response delivered to the client. Hence to avoid that the request processing time appears to be much longer than it needs to be, as these other API requests can take up to multiple seconds to be fully processed.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [**queues**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) e.g. create a custom database table, and write to it within the `rest_post_dispatch` or [`rest_pre_serve_request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_pre_serve_request/)  filter just before it is dispatched.

Then you can bulk process the queue (first record in is the first record out) via e.g. `wp-cron` and the user will not be affected by that potentially heavy processing. A custom column for the processing *status* might be useful as well.

With a real cron (not wp-cron) you could better control the timing/frequency of the processing.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hooks

I don't think the exact thing you're looking for exists. `serve_request()` [echos the output](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/36d24b511a8d400f3cfd223f8d739d70d36e1f56/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php#L545-L551), and then returns to `rest_api_loaded()`, which [immediately `die`s](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/36d24b511a8d400f3cfd223f8d739d70d36e1f56/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L418-L421).

The only action that runs after the request is `echo`'d to the output buffer is [`shutdown`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/shutdown/). That's a callback for [`register_shutdown_function()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php), so it runs after all the normal code paths have finished, but before the PHP process exits.

Even if you hooked into `shutdown`, though, the request still hasn't necessarily been *sent* to the client (that may vary a bit depending on server config, though).

I think it's worth considering if you need to wait until it's *sent*. Are there relevant differences between that point and the point at which the response has been *generated*? Using `rest_post_dispatch` -- *or even [`rest_pre_echo_response`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/36d24b511a8d400f3cfd223f8d739d70d36e1f56/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php#L522) if you want to be as late as possible* -- would give you access to the request and its response. The response isn't going to change, unless another plugin modifies it. If you're worried about that, you could hook in at a later priority to avoid that.

#### Batching

If your routes support it, you may want to look into [sending batch requests](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/20/rest-api-batch-framework-in-wordpress-5-6/). By default all requests are processed, even if some of them fail.

Yet another approach would be to create your own endpoint, which uses [an internal request](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/requests/#internal-requests) to do the batching.